# Why is ALTER DATABASE [test] SET [READ_UNCOMMITTED] ON GO not working in SQL Server 2008 R2?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

Why is

```
ALTER DATABASE [test] SET [READ_UNCOMMITTED] ON GO
```

not working? Is there any command so that I can set isolation level to `READ_UNCOMMITTED` for entire database in SQL Server 2008 R2.

Comment: set transaction isolation level read uncommitted  (GO on new line)

Comment: Are you getting an error message?

Comment: Remove `GO` and try again.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173763.aspx
`USE [test]; SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;`

Comment: i want to set isolation level for whole dataabse not for single transcation

Comment: i have remove go but no luck

Comment: i want to set isolation level for entire database not for single transaction.As we can set snapshot isolation level for entire database then why not able to set read uncommited for entire database

Comment: Why in the world would you want to do this? This is incredibly dangerous to say the least. This would be like sticking NOLOCK on every single query. This means you are ok with mostly accurate data most of the time. Additionally there are some other nasty things that happen. http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/

Comment: You cannot change the default isolation level for the entire database.

Comment: Thank you for your support.............

Answer (score 2):

> is there any command so that I can set isolation level to
>   READ_UNCOMMITTED for entire database in SQL server 2008 r2.

No. According the [Books Online reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522682.aspx), the only database options related to isolation levels are READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT and ALLOWSNAPSHOT_ISOLATION.

`READ_UNCOMMITTED` (and the NOLOCK hint) is generally a bad idea as that can cause not only uncommitted data to be returned, data can be skipped or duplicated in the result.  If you are concerned about blocking, consider setting the 'READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT' database option so that row versioning instead if locking is used to provide read consistency in the default `READ_COMMITTED` isolation level.